# Merge two xsd file in one xsd with c#

Tags: c#, xsd

i want to merge two xsd files to one xsd using c#.
how can i do it with c#? can anyone help me?

Comment: How do you mean 'merge' - do you want an xml document that validates against both schemas?

Comment: for example two like this http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp

and i want to merge to one file

Comment: I think it would be easier to understand if you give an example with the two inputs and what you want to have in the end.

Comment: for example, i have a xsd, and the second xsd only have a <xs:element, how can i copy this element, to the other xsd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for `<xsd:import />` or `<xsd:include />` see [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256480.aspx) for differences and restrictions.

**Your main schema document**

*Main.xsd*

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:import schemaLocation="Imported.xsd" />

    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="localElement" />
                <xsd:element ref="importedElement" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

**Your imported schema document**

*Imported.xsd*

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="importedElement">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="someElement" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```